# PHP mySql Actionscript ' "

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert couple of words in mySql database via php with flash interface. Since the words are in foreign language some of the letters are typed as ' and ". When I try to insert these letters I get error from mySql/php.

Can letter(symbols) like mentioned above be inserted in mySql? If yes, what changes do I need to make (Actionscript, PHP, mySql). The data type in mySql is varChar.

Comment: Please show some code and the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping them with a backslash (`\`).  Replace `'` with `\'` and `"` with `\"`

Comment: There are functions for that. It's not a good idea to try and do this manually.

Comment: and there are other characters that ought to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

In your mysql query use this function - 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php.

Comment: That depends on which mysql wrapper he is using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` (or `mysql_real_escape_string`).

Comment: AS codes

s_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callPhp);

function callPhp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var urlR:URLRequest = new URLRequest("site.php");
    var urlL:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var urlV:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
   
    urlV.nepali = nepali_txt.text;
    urlR.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    urlR.data = urlVariables;
    urlL.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, g);
    urlL.load(urlRequest);

function g(e:Event):void
{
   var urlLR:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
   var VR:URLVariables = new URLVariables(urlLR.data);
   if(VR.answer == "Yes")
  {   
  }
}

Comment: php code

<?php
    $nepali = $_POST['nepali'];
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("nepaliHangman",$connection);

    $query = "INSERT INTO words(`nepali`) VALUES ('$nepali')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result)
    { 
        echo "&answer=No";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "&answer=Yes";
    }

?>

Comment: I looked through we debugging proxy and it show that the values of ' and " are sent as %27 and %22